# How to pass custom data into Highcharts graph click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is possible to pass custom data when rendering a Highcharts graph (funnel, in this case), so that when I bind a click event, I can use this custom data point?

Currently, all that I can get is the "name" `event.point.name`, which I provide for the Label, but I also want to pass a `song_id` too.

http://jsfiddle.net/y4a2end3/1/

Is there a place in the graph code that I can add another data point, like "song_id"?

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Song Plays',
        data: [
           ['song_name1',123, 'song_id_1'], /* song_id_1 would be the custom data */
           ['song_name2',234, 'song_id_2']
        ]
    }]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to attach additional data to points in a series you can initialize the points that need additional data as objects instead of arrays/ints. For example, with your code you could do:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Song Plays',
    data: [
       {x:'song_name1', y:123, songid:'song_id_1'},
       {x:'song_name2', y:234, songid:'song_id_2'}
    ]
}]
```

You can then get it from the point on click as `event.point.songid`. See [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/berhn09z/1/) using point click and tooltip.

Note that in many cases `x` in the object will not be required. It is often automatic and sequential.

Comment: How to do this with HighCharts Android ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
alert(event.point.series.userOptions.data[event.point.x][2])
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y4a2end3/2/

Or this:

```
alert(event.point.series.userOptions.data[event.point.series.data.indexOf(event.point)][2]);
```